# apexcharts legend with values

Tags: javascript, legend, apexcharts

I have created a apexcharts. now i want to show all series data in legend like this
[i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RaAz.png)

my code -

```
new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#noOfPoc"), {
    series: [32, 2, 1, 1],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'donut',
      toolbar: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    labels: ['Completed', 'WIP', 'Drop', 'On Hold'],
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          return opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex]
        },
    },
  }).render();

  new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#noOfPoc"), {
    series: [pocCompleted, pocWip, pocOnHold, pocDrop],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'donut',
      toolbar: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    labels: ['Completed', 'WIP', 'Drop', 'On Hold'],
    dataLabels: {
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          return opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex]
        },
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
      offsetY: 80
    }
  }).render();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the legend label by providing the function which formats the legend label to the [`legend.formatter`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/legend/).

You can consider declaring the `customLegendFormatter` function to standardize the legend item output to all charts.

```js
let customLegendFormatter = (seriesName, opts) => {
  return `
        <div class="legend-item-label">${seriesName}</div>
        <div class="legend-item-value">${opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex]}</div>
    `;
};
```

Provide the `customLegendFormatter` to `legend.formatter`.

```js
new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#noOfPoc'), {
  ...,
  legend: {
    formatter: customLegendFormatter,
  },
}).render();
```

Customize the styling for the label and value as below:

```
.legend-item-label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 75px;
}

.legend-item-value {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 25px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vou6fg?file=index.html)